# argv function and string as address in C language

Tags: c, arrays, string, argv, double-pointer

Question.
How come the strings such as "C Programming" is compiled as address values as following?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 void ShowAllString(int argc, char * argv[]) 
 {
     int i;
     for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
        printf("%s \n", argv[i]);
 }

 int main(void)
 {
     char * str[3]={
         "C Programming",
         "C++ Programming",
         "JAVA Programming"  };

    ShowAllString(3, str);
    return 0;
  }
```

My analogy was like the following... please correct me if you can.

char * argv[] if in parameter, that is equivalent to char ** argv  .
So the function is like void ShowAllString(int argc, char ** argv) to receive double pointer as argument. So it makes sense to have str as parameter because str is the name of the array char * str[3] and str is double pointer here as array name.
char * str[3] is an array that is supposed to have three elements of pointers.... but how come such strings instead of address values are placed next to char * str[3]... this is where I am stuck!

Please help me!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking? `char *` is a string. You can do `char * x = "asdf";` Your program is going to put the string "asdf" somewhere in memory, and return a pointer to the first character.

Comment: @Porkbutts `char *` is a *type*. "String" is a representation of values. You can use `char *` to *point at* strings, but that type isn't synonymous with the term "string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, `char[]` is a pointer to where an array of `char` are stored, one after another in memory. As it happens, this is a good way to store a string. In your code, you are creating an array of 3 pointers to arrays of `char`. The first of which, `str[0]`, points to where the sequence of `char` "C Programming" is stored in memory, and so on.

(In everyday English one would generally call "a sequence of `char`" a "string", but technically, as the first comment correctly points out, this implies that `char[]` must by definition mean a string, which it doesn't.)

You pass a pointer to this array of pointers to the function, which then retrieves the pointers to each of the arrays of `char` ("strings"), which the `printf` line uses to get the strings (arrays of `char`) and print them.

Comment: `char[]` is a *type* (and an incomplete one, at that). "String" is a representation of values. You can (and *should*, when possible) use `char[]` to *store* strings, but that type isn't synonymous with the term "string".

Comment: @modifiablelvalue You are correct, I have tried to improve my answer to reflect your point of correction.

Answer (score 1):

When an array name is passed as parameter, it decays into a pointer. In your code, you have an array of 3 pointers. Therefore it decays into a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: I wonder when the term *decays* was originally used to describe the conversion of an array expression to a pointer expression. It has such a negative connotation, as though the array has ceased to live and is breaking down... I don't like it.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: "Decay" has been used to describe this process as long as I can remember.  I don't know if this is the right place to discuss etymology, but "decay" is only correct term I know of for this process, I know of no synonyms.

Comment: @DietrichEpp The C standard uses the word "convert", and by English definition "decay" just doesn't seem correct. An array, like all objects, might "decay" when it reaches the end of it's lifetime.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: Yes, they are "converted", but "decay" is more specific here.  It's not really appropriate to complain about common, accepted terminology -- the term "decay" might not tickle you the right way, but all your griping will not change the fact that it is the correct, specific term.  Try doing a Google search for this, with and without using the word "decay" in your query, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I used my dictionary to determine that the use of "decay" is incorrect in this case. I'm sure, if you ask an English professor (such as my partner), he/she will agree: Arrays do not *rot* to pointers.

Comment: ... and the standard explicitly uses the word "convert". It's been that way for as long as I can remember, and it was accepted by the forefathers of C, as well as many other well-known and respected figures, professors and the likes.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: The dictionary is not an acceptable reference for technical definitions, an English professors are usually not experts on technical matters, and the C standard is not the only source for terminology.  Do a Google search for "array decay", or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying -- search for "convert" in the answers to that question.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: It is also not appropriate to argue here in the comments: "decay" is already accepted terminology, this is not the appropriate forum to change that fact.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27218/discussion-between-modifiable-lvalue-and-dietrich-epp)